# Can only boot into Ubuntu if I choose 6.2.0-39-generic or 6.5.0-14-generic (recovery mode)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, boot

I can only boot into Ubuntu suddenly if I choose either 6.5.0-14-generic in **recovery mode** or 6.2.0-39-generic normally. But this setting does not persist so I have to enter GRUB everytime I start the PC.

I believe that the automatic update GUI "Actualizations" in the task bar in Kubuntu installed the new Kernel a day before together with a bunch of other packages. Which is why everything worked fine in the evening still and the next morning (yesterday) I could not boot and would wonder why and how to get this solved.

I don't know what kind of problems this hints to. Whether it only hints to problems with the kernel 6.5.0-14-generic or (also) to other problems?

How do I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This should help; that grub remember your last boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/252996/how-to-make-grub-remembers-what-i-boot-last-time/253004#253004    and `dkms status` please [edit] your question for this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to remove the buggy kernel:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic
```

Or, you can set the working kernel in your `grub` configuration file.

To list the kernel in order:

```
grep -P "menuentry" /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -d "'" -f2
```

Then set the `GRUB_DEFAULT=n` in `/etc/default/grub`,  `0` is the current and the first kernel in the list above.

###### The command line way:

In your `/etc/default/grub` you should have:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=false
```

Then set the desired kernel version:

```
sudo grub-set-default <menuentry>
```

e,g:

```
sudo grub-set-default "Ubuntu with Linux  6.5.0-14-generic"
```

Verify:

```
grub-editenv list
```

To unset the selected kernel use `grub-set-default unset`.

##### GUI way

Starting from Ubuntu 20.04 `grub-customizer` is available from `universe` repository. Install it then set the desired kernel on the top of the list .

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

To make it work when a new kernel is installed, make "previously booted entry" as default entry in the ""General settings""

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But sadly, it doesn't work for me. I tried both options and in both cases it throws me directly into the settings menu of the DELL firmware. I still need to press shift and then choose the right version in GRUB. :(

Comment: @vonspotz could you add the output of grep command to your question?

Comment: @vonspotz See my edit, please.

Comment: Sure. Please excuse the delay in my response. "$ grep -P "menuentry" /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -d "'" -f2
if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
  menuentry_id_option=""
export menuentry_id_option
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-14-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-14-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-39-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-39-generic (recovery mode)
UEFI Firmware Settings
"

Comment: And output of `grub-editenv list` is: "$ grub-editenv list
saved_entry=gnulinux-advanced-d6ee11bc-b19d-4a7f-a2ac-89dee99b6fdc>gnulinux-6.2.0-39-generic-advanced-d6ee11bc-b19d-4a7f-a2ac-89dee99b6fdc"

Comment: @vonspotz Use `grub-customizer` . it is very easy.

Comment: Dear GAD3R, thank you for your advice about grub-customizer. I did two things. I fit the order of kernels to start accordingly but this had no effect until I additionally chose the 6.2.0-39-generic as default in the second tab. Do you think I did something wrong with the /etc/default/grub file? I think the difference is the following:

Comment: `GRUB_DEFAULT` wasn't just set to but to `Ubuntu with Linux  6.5.0-14-generic` but to `Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-39-generic`. It also created further entries I think. But especially eye-catching is that it added `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` with value=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`. I don't know why this seems to solve everything but it did.

Comment: On the other hand, how probable is it that a kernel update is obviously so buggy that you cannot boot your system anymore? The question seems to cry for its own thread.